# Get system hour change event in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, notifications

I want be get notified when system hour changes. Like from 9am to 10am or 5pm to 6pm. Basically in my application I want to change the display on hourly basis. I know I can get the change by calculating manually. I just curious is there any other way so I can be get notified when system hour will change automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no angular2 built in service for that, but you could create your own.

Here is a simple service to demonstrate how it could be done:

```js
@Injectable()
class TimeNotifyService {

  private _lastHour;
  private _lastMinute;
  private _lastSecond;

  public hourChanged = new Subject<number>();
  public minuteChanged = new Subject<number>();
  public secondChanged = new Subject<number>();

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => this.timer(), 2000); // just a delay to get first hour-change..
  }

  private timer() {
    const d = new Date();
    const curHour = d.getHours();
    const curMin = d.getMinutes();
    const curSec = d.getSeconds();

    if (curSec != this._lastSecond) {
      this.secondChanged.next(curSec);
      this._lastSecond = curSec;
    }

    if (curMin != this._lastMinute) {
      this.minuteChanged.next(curMin);
      this._lastMinute = curMin;
    }

    if (curHour != this._lastHour) {
      this.hourChanged.next(curHour);
      this._lastHour = curHour;
    }

    // timeout is set to 250ms JUST to demonstrate the seconds-change..
    // if only hour-changes are needed, there is NO reason to check that often ! :)
    setTimeout(() => this.timer(), 250);
  }
}
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/QJCSnlMKpboteXbIYzqt?p=preview

Comment: Okay. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Couldn't you just calc the difference to the next full hour and then set the timeout to that distance instead of checking 4x per second if the hour has changed?

Comment: Sure, its just for the seconds-demo. :) I'll place a comment to that line!

Comment: Upvoted anyway, I was just curious if there was a reason :)